# Write from http request to jpg directly

Tags: image, format, jpeg, python-3.5

I have a script that downloads images from several websites. I don't know the format of the file, and it can vary.

What I do:

```
if response.status_code is requests.codes.ok:
    with iopen(path, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(response.content)
```

It creates an image at the specified path. However, sometimes the file I download is in the PNG format, and has an important size. As size matters, I would like to transform it directly to the jpg format, with some sort of compression, to reduce the space of the file on the disk.

How can I do that ? The solution must be compatible with python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my own answer:

```
import io
from PIL import Image

if response.status_code is requests.codes.ok:
    io = io.BytesIO(response.content)
    im = Image.open(io).convert('RGB').save('test.jpg)
```